# Which ad_group_criterion fields to combine with ad_group_audience_view in Google Ads Beta API

Tags: api, google-ads-api, awql

I am looking into the [Google Ads (Beta) API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start) and I want to query for the [ad_group_audience_view](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/fields/ad_group_audience_view) values, but I am not sure which [ad_group_criterion](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/fields/ad_group_criterion) fields are relevant for this view.

E.g. for the [topic_view](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/fields/topic_view), a related field in ad_group_criterion was [ad_group_criterion.keyword.text](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/fields/ad_group_criterion#ad_group_criterionkeywordtext):

```
SELECT ad_group_criterion.keyword.text FROM topic_view
```

Comment: As a more general question, is there documentation that links the views to their regarding attributes in the criterion? I did not find it.

Comment: Cross link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adwords-api/russler%7Csort:date/adwords-api/jyF_zMwSV90/lzsxqxupFgAJ